# Change value of PesonOrGroup 'Show field' value with powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, powershell, person-or-group

Using SharePoint 2013 enterprise on-premises.

Last week a user recommended changing the 'show field' value from the default to 'Account' on our task lists. This is hundreds of changes as we have 220+ sites (and growing) so naturally I'm looking at PowerShell to accomplish this. I'm not clear on how to set the 'show field' value once I've gotten my reference to the column.

```
$column = $List.Fields[$ColumnName]
$column .. ??
```

Hoping that someone here can show me the way on that.

Person Or Group Type:

[image: Person Or Group Type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below to set "Show Field" to "Account":

```
$column.LookupField = "Name";
$column.Update();
```

**Source**: [Setting 'Show field' for 'Person or Group' type column using PowerShell in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/setting-show-field-for-person-or-group-type-column-using-powershell-in-sharepoint2)

Comment: Thats a good find however it doesn't work on the 'Assigned To' column that I'm trying to modify. This is on the task list. The error is 'The Property 'LookupField' cannot be found on this object. ...'

Comment: I don't have 2013 environment to test it right now. Let me check if it is available in SP online >> tasks list >> "Assigned To" field.

Comment: Did you try the exact same code given in above link in answer?

Comment: Yes. in the $mylist.Fields I specified Assigned To and in the Lookup Field I set it as 'Name' which is equivalent to 'Account; on the list you provided. The error is:Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s):
"<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"
At C:\scripts\SP\UserColumn.ps1:8 char:1
+ $mycolumn.Update();